# close Javafx class application in java application

Tags: java, webview, javafx

i have an application in java, and this have a one popup with javafx application (embed videos from Youtube). I see this correctly but when i close this popup, the javafx thread not close and javafx application running in background. This is my javafx class:

```
public class JavaFXClass extends Application {
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final WebView webview = new WebView();
    /*...*/
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //I need stop javafx when this class close.
                }
            });
        }  
    });
    stage.show();
}

public static void LoadClass(String Data) { //I use this function to load class
    /*...*/
    launch(); //return error when i re-call this function (already launch).
}
```

If i put `webview.getEngine().load(null); Platform.exit();` code in the "OnCloseRequest" works fine but an exception is created ("Attempt to call defer when toolkit not running")

i need use `webview.getEngine().load(null);` or similar because if i not use this, the video in webview remain playing in background. And if i not use `Platform.exit()` the main frame crashes (lock).

Sorry for my bad english, tried to write the best I could

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
[...]
stage.setOnCloseRequest(this.getCloseSystemEvent());
}

public EventHandler<WindowEvent> getCloseSystemEvent() {
    return new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    };
}
```

Also, you should check the concurrency API. Your code prevents the runtime from closing the thread properly.